# Returning a Boolean from variable declaration

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a conditional statement to serve as a exception in styles.  My logic is to find location of current navigation, if navigation has a logo class `{expression}`

**Script**

```
 $('li.navCenter').on('click', function () {
   var findActiveLi = $('.footerUl').find(".currentFooterNav");//fine location of current navitation
   var logoTarget = $(findActiveLi > ".logo"); // finds if  currentnavli has logo class
    if ($(logoTarget) == true) {
        $("ul.logoUl > li").removeClass('orange blue green pink').addClass('grayLogo').css({
            'background-color': ''
        });
    }
});
```

**HTML** (*.currentFooterNav will move around*)

```
    <footer id="footer">
  <nav>
    <ul class="footerUl">
      <li id="worksFooterNavi" class="navi"><a href="#">works</a></li>
      <li id="aboutFooterNavi" class="navi"><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li class="homeFooterNavi navi currentFooterNav currentAll"><a href="#" title="logo">
        <div class="logo activeFooter">
          <ul class="logoUl">
            <li class="orange"></li>
            <li class="blue"></li>
            <li class="green"></li>
            <li class="pink"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </a> ​
      </li>
      <li id="contactFooterNavi"  class="navi"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      <li id="followFooterNavi"  class="navi"><a href="#">follow</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

how can i make this line return a boolean == true; when necessary?
`var logoTarget = $(findActiveLi > ".logo");`

Comment: Hiya, in your html I cannot see `navCenter` ?

Comment: Hiya nopes :) `$('li.navCenter')` will not work as `navcentre` class is not there bruv!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can also use

```
var $logoTarget = $(findActiveLi).has('.logo').length;
if($logoTarget > 0){
 // your code
```

Comment: fixed the code sorry (tried paring it down and it didnt work as well as planed)

Comment: @Joy I reckon HTML in OP is invalid and `has` or `hasClass` should suffice the need of checking if class is there. `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit, Sir `hasClass` wont work as `.logo` is on descendant, not on `findActiveLi`.

Comment: @joy does .has traverse through all children looking for the logo class?

Comment: That won't return a boolean. (Which may or may not matter to OP: it would still work in an `if` condition since a non-zero numeric is truthy.)

Comment: @MatthewHarwood, yes it does, but that is not the case with `hasClass`, it just checks for `.logo` on the currently selected set.

Comment: @nnnnnn, Yes Sir it wont return boolean, but will serve OP's purpose well for the reason you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
 var $logoTarget = $(".logo",findActiveLi[0]); // finds if  currentnavli has logo class
 if ($logoTarget.length > 0) {
```

Comment: wouldnt the <a> interfere with this?

Comment: @Engineer Hmm interesting way to approach this issue, anyhow +1 to you as well bruv!

Comment: You don't really need length > 0 right? length will return 0 if it's not found and that's falsey

Answer (score 1):

```
var $logoTarget = $(findActiveLi).hasClass('logo');
```

> [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to furhter expand to the answer. It's important to make correct reasonings on the matter:

If you write:

```
var logoTarget = $(findActiveLi > ".logo");
```

it means:

> Compare the variable `findActiveLi` and see if it's *greater than* (?) the *string* `".logo"`, then pass the *result of this comparison* (between a JQuery object and a string?! a bit like comparing apples to airplanes...) to the function `"$"` in the hope that something happens :)

As you may imagine, from a programmer's point of view it's complete nonsense. Using a plugin like JQuery doesn't mean that the regular program syntax it flushed away: a ">" sign, used outside a literal string, still means "greater than" ad is used for comparison (mostly on *numerical* values).

If `findActiveLi` was a **string** (which is not), you could have done:

```
var logoTarget = $(findActiveLi + "> .logo");
                                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

by string concatenation (f.ex. if findActiveLi was ".activeLi", that expression would become `".activeLi > .logo"` making a valid selector because ">" is now declared as part of a string).

Still it will not work for you because it is not a string but an **object**. The correct approach to objects is to use their methods and properties, so we finally fall back to what the other users told you:

```
var logoTarget = $(findActiveLi).has('.logo').length;
```

That means:

> Use `findActiveLi` ad a **JQuery object** (element or element collection); as such it has the "`has(selector)`" method that enables me to see if it contains other elements as specified by selector, giving me another element collection; as a collection we have the `.length` property to count how many of these elements we have found.

Comment: thanks you so much could you accually futher explain why @engineer's answer worked?  I think it's same concept but the symantics dont quite make sense

Comment: Because the jQuery function ( `$(...)` ) has also the syntax:
`$( selector [ , context ]  )`, which means "select the element(s) specified by *selector* whithin the *context* [which can be another element] specified."
In this case, Engineer is searching for element(s) of class `.logo` in the context (roughly it means "inside") of the first `findActiveLi` element found (hence the `[0]`).

Comment: pretty awesome logic.  Although seems a bit more volatile than has() answer.  What if the length distance changes and I add something to the markup